The origins of uniform circular motion
Bohr's model of the atom states that electrons orbit the nucleus in uniform circular motion, with the Coulomb force providing the centripetal acceleration necessary to maintain this motion. How does this situation come about, though?
In an empty universe, an electron zooms by a nucleus (simplified as a positive point charge) with an initial velocity at some angle to the radius vector between the two charges. Initially, the nucleus is defined as stationary and the distance between the two charges is r.

How may such a situation lead to this electron orbiting the nucleus?

Well, Bohr's model is not a correct picture of reality, so there's no way to answer the question of how this situation comes about. If you want to ask how an atom can capture an electron quantum mechanically, then that's another question.

As mentioned in other answers, Bohr's model is not an accurate model of an atom. Yet, we can continue under the assumption that it is valid:

... an electron zooms by a nucleus ...

As per your diagram, this will almost never lead to a successful circular orbit around the proton. Note that we assume the proton to not move(effectively having infinite mass, as compared to the electron). We can find the equation of the trajectory the electron would follow, and I would guess it would be some second degree equation. We could then find the necessary conditions(from the trajectory) for the orbit to be circular or elliptical.
Bohr's model simply gives us the relation between velocity and radius of a single electron system. For your situation to come about, we have the following equations:

Bohr's quantization rule

$$mvr = n\hbar$$

Centripetal force(Coulomb's law)

$$\frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$$
Solving these two equations simultaneously, we get the necessary condition for a circular orbit.
Example
For a hydrogen atom
Let $k = 1/4\pi\epsilon_0$,
The radius of an electron in its ground state,
$$r = a_0 = \frac{\hbar^2}{mke^2} \approx 52.9 \text{ pm}$$
And its velocity,
$$v= \frac{ke^2}{\hbar} \approx 2.18 \cdot 10^6 \text{ m s}^{-1}$$
So, as per your electron zooming by a stationary proton, if it has velocity $v$ and its distance from the proton is $a_0$, then it would form a stable hydrogen atom, as per Bohr's model.
So, in short, it just happens by chance.(According to Bohr's model)

The Bohr model only considers atoms in stasis or after transitions between energy levels. It is not a model of the dynamics or of how the electron and nucleus came together. It was successful in providing a basis for the Rydberg formula for the spectrum lines of the hydrogen atom, but not much else. It was an important step in the development if quantum mechanaics, but its uses are limited, and this model was replaced later with quantum theory.
